# Mic is not working when connected to SB Audigy 1550 RX sound card

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, soundcard

My mic is not working on Ubuntu 22.04 when connected to a SB Audigy 1550 RX sound card. I've checked alsamixer but I have no clue what these volume bars mean. I have tried turning up the "Amic" but that didnt do anything.

[image: Alsamixer screenshot]

I've selected the sound card in settings to applications like discord but still nothing happens.

One thing that does work is plugging my mic to the motherboard panel in the back of my desktop PC but that yields a poor quality and doesn't solve the problem of my mic not working on my sound card.

Sound Card ports, I've plugged in my mic into mic 1:

[image: Screenshot]

I've used hdajackretasker and it's pretty much useless when it keeps saying that the devices are busy so I cannot make any changes even when I have closed all my applications.

---

I'm on:

- **Pulseaudio 15.99.1**
- **Ubuntu 22.04.2**
- **SoundCard: SoundBlaster Audigy SB 1550 RX**

My speakers work as I'm connected through a **USB audio interface Scarelette 2i2**

My mic is a **standalone mic (ModMic)** with an aux cable connected to the sound card in mic 1 port

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I believe it's a bug in pulseaudio, but there is a workaround.

I think in alsamixer you need Mic Select set to Mic1 (or plug your mic to Mic2). There are two "Analog Mix" settings in alsamixer, one for Playback (F3) and one for Capture (F4). The one in Capture has to be set to non-zero value. See also [this Mint forum thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=283762).

If this doesn't solve it, additionaly change profile for the sound card in pavucontrol to "Pro Audio". After that new input and output devices appear. I use `CA0108/CA10300 [Sound Blaster Audigy Series] (SB1550 Audigy 5/Rx) Pro` for output and `CA0108/CA10300 [Sound Blaster Audigy Series] (SB1550 Audigy 5/Rx) Pro 2` for input. See also [this PipeWire issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/2006).

Sometimes with "Pro Audio" profile I have no output. Switching to "Analog Stereo Duplex" and back to "Pro Audio" seems to solve it.

I'm on PipeWire 0.3.65, PulseAudio 16.1, Debian 12.